# RegEx to match all sets of items that have part of specific value

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use RegEx to filter all sets of items that have part of a specific value in a  capture group that I have defined.

I have to check if the fifth capture group contains at least part of a specific text.

**My string:**

> First Item;Second Item;Third Item;Fourth Item;First Word;Sixth
> Item?First Item;Second Item;Third Item;Fourth Item;Second Word;Sixth
> Item?First Item;Second Item;Third Item;Fourth Item;Can't Capture This
> Set;Sixth Item

**RegEx that works for exact word:**

```
(?:^|\?)([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);(Second Word);([^;\?$]+)
```

The problem is that I need this RegEx to work to capture only part of the word.

**Not Working:**

```
(?:^|\?)([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);(.*Word.*);([^;\?$]+) >
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question would be clearer if, between "My String:" and "RegEx that works for exact word:", you insert a section "Desired Result:". When giving examples it's always helpful to the reader to show the desired result.

Comment: @Caca Please kindly upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[^;]*` instead of `.*` because you have semi-colons as field delimiters:

```
(?:^|\?)([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]*Word[^;]*);([^;?]+)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/yiWAA8/1). `([^;]*Word[^;]*)` will match zero or more characters other than semi-colons, then a `Word` and zero or more characters other than semi-colons.